# Meaning of the verb TO HIT in "hit the road"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I wonder about the meaning of TO HIT  in this kind of context,

> Follow this footpath and you’ll eventually hit the road.

There is also a song which goes as follows

> hit the road, Jack ...

Can anyone help me grasp the meaning of TO HIT in these specific context?

Comment: The meaning of your phrase can be found [here](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+the+road), or are you asking why the specific use of the word **hit**?

Comment: Slang for "to *strike* out upon a journey, to depart".   We can also say, "Do you want to hit a few pubs|bars after work on Friday? I have to hit the head. Do you wanna hit a movie? We hit a few art galleries on our trip to New York." and there it means "to visit".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo You're completely right that it's simply part of the definition of hit. I said as much with a link to the *OED* definition of the word and have gotten nothing but downvotes, apparently for personal reasons from separate entries. How do you get in touch with an admin about site abuse like that?

Comment: @Ily: I don't much like anonymous downvotes but they're allowed on SE sites. I'd be all for raising the reputation requirement to leave downvotes to at least 5,000.

Answer (score 4):

The first *hit* means *to encounter, to come across*:

> [hit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hit)
>   verb (used with object), hit, hitting.
>
> 14. to come or light upon; meet with; find:
>       to hit the right road.
>
> (Dictionary.com)

If you follow that footpath, you will eventually find the road.

I would say the second one is part of an idiom: *hit the road*. In that context, the speaker is commanding Jack to leave, to go away. However, in a different context, it can simply mean to begin a journey.

> - [hit the road](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hit-the-road)
>     to leave; go away
>     to start or resume travelling
>     (Collins Dictionary)
> - [hit the road](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hit+the+road)
>     Fig. to depart; to begin one's journey, especially on a road trip; to leave for home. *It's time to hit the road. I'll see you. We have to hit the road very early in the morning.*
>     (TFD)

Comment: Yes, "hit the road" is an idiom. That said, the sense of "hit" being used in it is not solely idiomatic. It's not *sui generis* the way "cats and dogs" are in "raining cats and dogs".

Answer (score 1):

The second definition in merriam webster gives

> to cause to come into contact

The word is so short, it subsumes multiple meanings depending on context.

> to discover or meet especially by chance

This seems to fit finding the right road.

> To deliver a blow

This seems to fit with the song, as a powerful, aversive connotation is implied, as if Jack is let falling down to hit (his head on) the road. But its not quite as strong, I hope - maybe Jack will *meet* someone *by chance* anew, but the song doesn't care.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hit

Also, to hit the road is an idiom that means, *to leave*.

*to go on the road* would have a different meaning, to travel, so a different idiom is needed.

Answer (score -1):

**[Hit has a base sense of *violent* contact](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/87336), but is used figuratively to express *any* strong or emphatic contact.**

**The *hit* in**

> Head on over yonder and y'all'll hit the road sooner or later.

**is *reach* or *meet*, just sexed up a little.** It's worth noting that Americans will associate this expression with places that don't *have* paved roads (i.e., the sticks) and, sometimes, with the people who live there (yokels). It's a bog standard sense of the verb, though. (Sense II.11.ff. at the *OED*, which notes its odd history: the *reach* or *meet* sense of *hit* was the word's standard sense in Old Norse but mostly disappeared in English only to reappear in colloquial American speech.)

Similarly, *to go* or *to set out on a journey* was the base sense of [*strike*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/191633), one of *hit*'s primary synonyms. **The hit in**

> Hit the road, bub.

has a long history into Old English as *strike out upon* and **means *step briskly*,** not so much that one needs to be running but that one moves sharply and emphatically away from this place.

It may feel a little odd even to a native speaker (notice the answers that only want to treat *hit the road* as a pat phrase) since modern English tends to use *hit* for blows from a fist or hand-held tool and uses *kick* for strikes from one's feet. It's part-and-parcel of the actual English term, though, back to Old Norse and Old English, revived by an American tendency to indulge in stronger and more violent means of expression.

Comment: Anyone care to explain which part of the *OED* they have a problem with?

Comment: Still no? How do you get in touch with an admin when people seem to be downvoting sourced and accurate answers for personal reasons?